# How python-wsgi manage http requests?

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I just have a problem and also be a clarification. What is the actual way that the wsgi program manage the hits coming to the application ? Are there separate threads for each request or one thread for all the requests ? Then what happen if the number of requests at a time will increase ?

I now there are some Apache configurations for threads and processes like

> WSGIDaemonProcess

Also found some answers on http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading

But can any one explain me how the exact way that wsgi manage the requests for the application ? How can we tune that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some bed time read/watching for you:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/python-interpreter-is-not-created-for.html
- http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdyzk/
- http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spcdg/

The document you already referred to should explain a lot about the process/thread model already.